# TinyMCE as comment editor - encoding issues

Tags: hooks, comments, tinymce, wp-editor, encoding

I've implemented TinyMCE as my comment form on both the front- and back-end, using the below code (sourced from some questions here):

```
// Enable TinyMCE as frontend comment editor for new comments
function wpse_64243_comment_editor( $field ) {

    if (!is_single()) return $field; //only on single post pages.

    global $post;
    ob_start();

    wp_editor( '', 'comment', array(
        'textarea_rows' => 15
    ) );

    $editor = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();

    //make sure comment media is attached to parent post
    $editor = str_replace( 'post_id=0', 'post_id='.get_the_ID(), $editor );
    return $editor;
}

add_filter( 'comment_form_field_comment', 'wpse_64243_comment_editor' );

// Enable TinyMCE as the backend comments editor
function cort_remove_editor_quicktags( $settings, $id ){
    global $pagenow; 
    if ( $id == 'content' && $pagenow === 'comment.php' ){
        $settings['tinymce'] = true;
    }
    return $settings;
}

add_filter( 'wp_editor_settings', 'cort_remove_editor_quicktags', 10, 2 );
```

But the comment encoding gets a little weird any time I go to edit it. While any formatting displays correctly in the admin view, and on the page all the tags are bolding/italicizing as they should, any time I try to edit the text with TinyMCE, I get this:

```
<!--On TinyMCE, in visual mode-->
<strong>asdfjkasld;f</strong>

<em>hjkdlhfaskdjfas</em>

<!--On TinyMCE, in text mode-->
&lt;strong&gt;asdfjkasld;f&lt;/strong&gt;

&lt;em&gt;hjkdlhfaskdjfas&lt;/em&gt;
```

If I "repair" the styles by removing the encoded tags and reformatting through TinyMCE, the next time I hit Edit on that comment, I get the same results as the above.

As far as I can tell, this has more to do with TinyMCE not decoding encoded text, since I have it set up outside its normal environment. I've tried changing the encoded entities in `tiny_mce_before_init`, but that hasn't worked. Are there any hooks for filtering the actual content of a post before it hits TinyMCE? Or is this a dead-end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's still unclear to me why this is happening, because all the encoding of `<` and `>` for comments looks the same as posts do in the database view, so I'm still unsure why TinyMCE is treating `post_content` vs `comment_content` differently. But ultimately, all that needs to happen is for the existing escaped HTML tags to get decoded when editing on the backend.

```js
jQuery( document ).on( 'tinymce-editor-init', function( event, editor ) {
    function htmlDecode(input) {
        var doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(input, "text/html");
        return doc.documentElement.textContent;
    }

    function fixTinyMCEComments() {
        var parent = document.querySelector("#content_ifr").contentDocument.children[0].querySelector("#tinymce");
        Array.from(parent.children).forEach(function(p) {
            p.innerHTML = htmlDecode(p.innerHTML);
        });
    }

    fixTinyMCEComments();
});
```

Register it wherever your `admin_enqueue_scripts` is called in `functions.php` - I enqueue it only on `comment.php`:

```
// Enable TinyMCE as the backend comments editor
function load_backend_comments_editor( $settings, $id ){
    global $pagenow; 
    if ( $id == 'content' && $pagenow === 'comment.php' ){
        $settings['tinymce'] = true;
        wp_enqueue_script( 'mytheme-admin' );
    }
    return $settings;
}
add_filter( 'wp_editor_settings', 'load_backend_comments_editor', 10, 2 );
```

This is a bit of a hack, because the implementation depends on TinyMCE maintaining its current node tree, but since this is on the backend for something that likely won't continue to be edited after a month or so, I'm okay with it. Any improvements are welcome, though!